# PHP - MSSQL Connection Issues

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I basically have a product description page that reads a product number from the URL and queries a MSSQL database to pull additional information to populate the page.  However, it seems to be randomly failing.  If it fails, a simple refresh of the page usually brings it back up, so it's not a data related issue.

We put in some while loops in an attempt to re-establish the connection or rerun the query, but this doesn't seem to be helping at all.  I also tried adding a sleep to see if it just needed more time to run the query, but that didn't help either.

Here are some of the code snippets:

```
$server = 'server';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'password');
$myDB = "database";
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $link)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

$tryconnect = 0;
while(!$link and $tryconnect < 10){
mssql_close($link);
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'password');
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $link)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
$tryconnect++;
};

$query = "select *,DBO.CustFile(".$accountnum.",ITEMNO) AS ALLOC from ourView where itemno = ".$itemno;
$result = mssql_query($query);
sleep(2);
$numofrows = mssql_num_rows($result);

//Try to reconnect up to 10 times if MSSQL connection fails
$iSQL = 0;
while ($numofrows == 0 and $iSQL < 10){
$result = mssql_query($query);
$numofrows = mssql_num_rows($result);
$iSQL++;
}
```

Comment: The [pdo driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) supports sql server. Why not try to use that instead?

Comment: Or [sqlsrv on windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)  and [dblib for linux](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php).